# Is cache miss a kind of interrupt/fault

Tags: exception, operating-system, segmentation-fault, interrupt

We know that a page miss in memory will bring a page fault, and the page handler must load the page into the physical memory. Here I wonder whether a miss in a cache is also a system fault? If not, what's the difference between a memory fault and a cache fault? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "cache fault" do you mean a cache miss in the L1/L2/L3 caches of the processor? If so, then no, it does not generate a fault, at least on every processor architecture that I've ever heard of.

The reason for this is that a page fault requires software intervention to decide whether the access was invalid, whether the access was to a page that was swapped out to disk, etc.  In contrast, a cache miss can by definition be handled by the processor itself - since it didn't cause a page fault, the data must already be stored in main memory or a lower-level cache, which is directly accessible to the processor. The processor will mechanically translate the address of the memory being accessed from virtual to physical and then asks the lower-level cache or main memory for the data.

The same idea applies to simultaneous multiprocessors, where a cache line might be invalidated by one core which writes to it, even though another core has it stored in a cache. The processor defines its own coherency protocol to ensure that the stale copy will not be read, usually either by forcing the core with the invalid cache line to refresh it from a lower-level cache, or by requiring it to watch a shared write bus where all processors can see values which are being written to.

Answer (score 1):

No, it simply causes a processor stall.  Perhaps an appropriate mental image is of one or more NOP instructions getting inserted into the pipeline.  Also called a "[bubble"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_stall).  Not so sure this is an appropriate model for what modern processors do but the effect certainly is the same, the processor stops executing instructions until the data becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

A *cache fault* is when a core is blocked to read/write because another core intends to read/write at the same time the very same data. This is an issue of multicore parallelism. For instance, consider that two cores (0 and 1) require a variable *x* from the RAM, a copy of x is placed on the highest level cache (L2 or L3) which is shared by all the cores, then a second copy of *x* is placed in the most internal cache (L1) of core 0 while core 1 request the very same variable to operate with. Core 1 must be *blocked* while the conflict of updating the value of the variable from core_0 is performed. The *blocking operation* is a cache fault.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody else has mentioned [TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) so far. Some CPUs (e.g. MIPS) have a software-filled TLB and a TLB miss actually triggers execution of the dedicated exception handler, which then needs to provide to the CPU the sought virtual to physical mapping. IOW, some cache misses/faults may not be handled automatically by hardware.